# passing props from parent to child in react class based component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am new to react and cannot figure out how to pass data received from the server from a parent component to a child component as such:

```
//parent component
class AlumniComponent extends React.Component {

    state = {
        profile : {},
        error: false
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        Axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1')
        .then(response=>{
            // console.log(response.data);
            this.setState({profile: response.data})
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            console.log(error);
            this.setState({error: true})        
        })
    }

    render() {

        const profile = this.state.profile;

        return(
            <AboutComponent data={profile} tab="about"/>
        );
    }
```

In my child component:

```
class AboutComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: {
                name: props.data   // <--- the props are coming coming from the parent component !? 
            },
            selectedOption: null,
        };
    }

render (){

return (
      <Form.Control type="text" value={JSON.stringify(this.state.data)} disabled />
);
}
```

the input value comes out as empty object: {"name":{}}

Comment: In the child, don't create a 2nd state for the same data. Let the parent manage the state and the child just consumes it as a prop so your `Form.Control` becomes `<Form.Control type="text" value={JSON.stringify(this.props.data)} disabled />`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try to stay away from storing `props` inside of `state` so that your `parent` and `children` components don't get out of sync. Instead, use what you need from the `props` inside of `children` and then if you need to store some other information based on the `props` that are passed, use `state` for that.

Here's an example:

```js
class AlumniComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    profile: {},
    isLoading: true,
    error: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          profile: data,
          isLoading: false
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({
          error: error.message,
          isLoading: false
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { profile, isLoading, error } = this.state;

    if (isLoading) {
      return `Loading`;
    }
    if (!isLoading && error) {
      return `Something went wrong`;
    }
    return <AboutComponent data={profile} />;
  }
}

class AboutComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    const initialState = {
       name: this.props.data.name,
       selectedOption: null
    }
    this.state = { ...initialState }
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      name: event.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { name } = this.state;

    return <input type="text" value={name} onChange={this.handleChange} />;
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AlumniComponent />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("app")
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Also, I don't know what the `<Form.Control />` component is expecting for the `value` property, but make sure you grab the right information that you need instead of passing the entire prop/object into it.

```js
class AboutComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      name: this.props.data.name
    }
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      name: event.target.name
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Form.Control 
        type="text" 
        value={this.state.name} 
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        disabled 
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and clear explanation.
I do get the value I expected now, but I am getting this warning:
"A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled."
There seems to be some conflicting information on this though. Everything I read tells me to set the initial values in the state first.
I was able to get rid of the error by simply adding some logic for the default value::
```
<Form.Control type="text" value={this.props.data.name || ""}  disabled />
```
Is this how you'd handle that? I will need to post the updated values to the server later.

Comment: Yes, that’s because you’re missing the handler that’s responsible for changing the value on the input field. I forgot what the exact prop for your case is though, but I will update the answer when I get to my computer.

Comment: Here’s an example - https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: @rsilva Have a look at the edited code snippet and example. This will take care of that warning and do what it needs to do.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot **this** `this.props.data` but this an anti pattern

```
 this.state = {
  data: {
    name: this.props.data,
  },
};
```

You should do it in `componentDidMount()`

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.setState({name:this.props.data.name})
}
```

Then:

```
 <Form.Control type="text" value={this.state.name} disabled />
```